# Firebase when is onAuthStateChanged triggered?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If I have my createUserWithEmailAndPassword function structured like this

```
    await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
        code stuff...
        return promise
    }).then(() => {
        ...
    }).catch(() => {
        ...
    }).finally(() => {
        ...
    })
```

When in the promise chain would the onAuthStateChanged observer fire-up?

Comment: This seems like something you could observe for yourself with some console logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onAuthStateChanged` observer is triggered only when a user either signs in or signs out.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged):

> Prior to 4.0.0, this triggered the observer when users were signed in, signed out, or when the user's ID token changed in situations such as token expiry or password change. After 4.0.0, the observer is only triggered on sign-in or sign-out.

> To keep the old behavior, see [firebase.auth.Auth.onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged)

That being said if you have the `onAuthStateChanged` observer, it'll trigger as soon as the user logs in and the code inside of your `.then()` block may or may not completely execute. If your auth observer redirects users to some other page if logged in, then there is a high chance that your user will be redirected before your then block completes.

If you need to execute some code after the user logs in, you should unsubscribe from the auth observer:

```js
const auth = firebase.auth()

const authObserver = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // redirect
  }
})


btnLogin.onclick = async function () {
  //unsubscribe
  authObserver()

  await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
        // onAuthStateChanged will trigger here if not disabled
        //code stuff...
        //return promise
    }).then(() => {
        // your code
    })
}
```